# How to read electron 'Local Storage' data outside electron app?

Tags: electron

How to read data under electron 'Local Storage' folder outside electron app?
In below example, `Local Storage/leveldb/000003.log` is apparently the data storage file.

```
# find Local\ Storage/
Local Storage/
Local Storage/leveldb
Local Storage/leveldb/CURRENT
Local Storage/leveldb/MANIFEST-000001
Local Storage/leveldb/000003.log
Local Storage/leveldb/LOG
Local Storage/leveldb/LOG.old
Local Storage/leveldb/LOCK
```

(I would prefer a node.js example, but any other language/runtime is acceptable)